# Can't join two tables in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: `md_reporting` and `md_campaigns`, I want to join them and do my query, however when I use this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM md_reporting,md_campaigns 
WHERE md_reporting.campaign_id = md_campaigns.campaign_id
```

I can't pool anything out from my database, I use this SQL query from phpMyAdmin and it returns the result I want.

Comment: does this query works fine on mysql shell

Comment: Check you PHP code properly or post some code here for help.

Comment: Try to run query in Mysql first and check whether it runs and error you are getting ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem???

Comment: @Demonedge post your PHP code here.

Comment: thank you guys, I found out that there is some hidden code in my project using the campaign_id and I have to point out which table this campaign_id belongs to by md_reporting.campaign_id or md_campaigns.campaign_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TABLE1.`name`, TABLE1.`name2`, TABLE2.`name3` FROM `md_reporting` AS TABLE1
LEFT JOIN `md_campaigns` AS TABLE2 ON TABLE1.`id` = TABLE2.`id`;
```

More examples: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score -1):

In any way, even though the php code is missing, I can see that there is an ambiguous/duplicate fields in the tables being selected: campaign_id is contained in both. Try something like the following:

```
SELECT md_reporting.example FROM md_reporting, md_campaigns WHERE md_reporting.campaign_id=md_campaigns.campaign_id
```

Where md_reporting.example is the column that you want to fetch.